# creating a new adb logcat text file in a python script

Tags: android, python, file, adb, logcat

How do I execute this logcat command via python?

```
adb logcat -d > log1.txt
```

I tried this but there is no file being created in the output folder. 
I did do a workaround and it worked.

I have another issue: The log1.txt file is populated. I am expected to copy lines with tag "sample" from log1.txt file to another new file. I wrote a function for this but only one instance of the tag line is getting printed in the new file where as the print statement before this print 3 lines in the output. Could someone plz help.

```
for line in open("log1.txt",'r'):        
    cmd="sample"
    if cmd in line:
        print line
        f = open('myfile','w')
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: You tried "this", and "this" is ???

Comment: cmd = "adb logcat -d>~/log1.txt"
time.sleep(10)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('out-file.txt', 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call(['adb','logcat', '-d'], stdout=f)
```

Comment: cmd = "adb logcat -d>~/log1.txt"
time.sleep(10)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

Comment: how do you copy the output into a file "parsedlog.txt"